# How to find the jar dependencies of jar files

Tags: jar, dependencies, jdeps

I'm trying to list the dependencies of 100+ jar files using jdeps, however, when I run 'jdeps -recursive -s -cp 'path/*' jarFile.jar' some dependencies are 'not found'. 
Is there a way to make sure that Jdeps finds ALL dependencies and if not, is there a good tool for finding the jar dependencies of jar files?